Scipy solve_ivp requests time out of bounds
My code solves a 1st order differential equation using Scipy's solve_ivp function and the standard RK45 solver. The code itself is reasonably large, and I will certainly attempt to produce a minimal working example if all else fails. However, there might already be a problem at a conceptual that stage, so I am hoping this is not a bug but just my lack of understanding.
The important part of the code is as follows:
nStep = 1000
time_arr = np.arange(nStep)
sol = solve_ivp(rhs_func, (0, self.nStep-1), [x0, ],
                t_eval=time_arr, args=(my_args_list,))

I would like to integrate the right hand side on the time interval [0, 999], as given by the 2nd argument, and and sample the result at integer values of time within that interval, as is given by the t_eval keyword argument.
It is my expectation that, internally, the solver would sample the right hand side at arbitrary floating-point times within the provided time interval. For many different values of my_args_list, it indeed does so. However, for some fairly reasonable argument values it attempts to sample the right hand side severely outside of the provided range. For example, it attempted to sample at 10062.831699320916, which is severely outside of the integration boundaries.
Am I right to assume that this behaviour is unexpected and is a bug (either of scipy or of my code)?
I would appreciate suggestions on what may be causing such behaviour.
EDIT: I was finally able to produce a minimal example for this bug. I solve a simple Integrator ODE dx/dt = k*[f(t) - x(t)] for some forcing vector f(t). Specifically, I provide a box signal between 0 and 10 seconds, such that f(t) = 2 for 2 <= t <= 4, and f(t) = 4 everywhere else.
# Libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import norm
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp

# Initialization
tmin = 0
tmax = 10
nStep = 1000
time_arr = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, nStep)

x_forcing_low = 1
x_forcing_high = 2
t_break_l = 2
t_break_r = 4
forcing = np.full(nStep, x_forcing_low)
idxs_pulse = np.logical_and(time_arr >= t_break_l, time_arr <= t_break_r)
forcing[idxs_pulse] = x_forcing_high

# Right hand side of a simple Integrator ODE dx/dt = k*[f(t) - x(t)] for some forcing vector f(t)

def dxdt(t, x, param):
    if (t < tmin) or (t > tmax):
        raise ValueError(f"{t} is out of bounds [{tmin}, {tmax}]")

    f_this = np.interp(t, time_arr, forcing)

    k, = param
    return k*(f_this - x)

# We go over different values of the integration rate, and test if solve_ivp works
kArr = 10 ** np.linspace(-3, 3, 20)
for k in kArr:
    try:
        sol = solve_ivp(dxdt, (tmin, tmax), [5, ], t_eval=time_arr, args=([k, ],))
        print(k, sol['success'])
    except ValueError as e:
        print(k, e)

The code demonstrates that for k=0.001 the solver solve_ivp attempts to sample time at t=12.5, which is out of bounds [0, 10]. However, it works as expected for all other values of k
I have also implemented an analytic solution for this case (omitted for brevity), and it clearly demonstrates that the solver starts progressively breaking down for values of k < 0.1, producing completely unreasonable solutions. I will produce a separate question, addressing accuracy of the forwards integration scheme, as the problems are likely to be related.

Please provide a short example that reproduces this issue. We can't help you without that.

@jared Yes, you can. You do not need a working example to tell me if my understanding of the arguments of solve_ivp is correct. Yes, I have read the documentation of solve_ivp, and could not find explicit mention of where it is allowed to sample. I am not asking for help with basic debugging. I am asking for help from somebody experienced in using solve_ivp.

No, solve_ivp should not be evaluating the function outside of the desired domain. Is it a bug? Without observing it for myself and doing tests, I cannot say. I don't even know if you're looking at the correct number to determine it's evaluating outside of the domain. One of first steps of debugging is assume the previous person didn't know what they were doing (if you assume they did then you might miss the problem simply because they already missed the problem).

"I am not asking for help with basic debugging." Your title said, "help debug".

Point taken, I will correct the title. Edit: Ah, you already did, thanks

solve_ivp might evaluate your function at times outside t_span, and that is not a bug.  See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9198

@WarrenWeckesser There is further discussion where it is called a bug and appears it will be fixed in the next version of scipy. Though I'm not sure if this is the actual cause of the issue here since it's being evaluated way outside the bounds (999 vs 10000).

The documentation of RK45 and the other stepper classes contains the explicit promise that no evaluation outside t_bound will occur. You can also limit the step size with the max_step argument, set it moderately large, like 10 in the current setup.

It would be good if you shared some code. Remember, this site isn't just about solving one-off problems–it's supposed to be pedagogical.

@jared Sorry for delay. I finally managed to produce an example

Numerical experiments for ODE solvers should also set and adapt the error tolerances. The defaults are usually only valid for educational examples, not for very slow or very fast dynamics.

@LutzLehmann, Thanks! It seems that increasing relative tolerance significantly improves the performance, including avoiding out of bounds jumps. I would love to understand how the relative tolerance translates to accuracy, but I guess that's a whole different topic.
